# response.sendRedirect("/test.jsp"); doesn't work

Tags: java, html, jsp, jsp-tags

I'm working with `jsp` and I have two conditions for redirect to some page, this is my code

```
<%
if(traer.getFormapacretro().equals("RELACIONESLABORALES")&&tarea.getEstado()==4)
{
System.out.println("::::::::::::::::RELACIONES"+tarea.getEstado()+"LABORALES:::::::::::::::::::::");
response.sendRedirect("/html/controltareas/viewpacrl.jsp");
}
else if(traer.getFormapacretro().equals("CAPACITACION")&&tarea.getEstado()==4)
{
System.out.println("::::::::::::::::CAPACITACION"+tarea.getEstado()+":::::::::::::::::::::");
response.sendRedirect("/html/controltareas/viewpaccapacita.jsp");

}
%>
```

But when the form is loaded it only shows results on the console but not redirect to the page in the condition, some help?

Comment: You should always do `return;` after sendRedirect, to prevent execution of the page continuing. Not that this will fix the problem, but it might.

Comment: Also if the jsp doing the redirecting is already in `/html/controltareas/` then you don't need to include `/html/controltareas/` when redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

You have to always use `return`; when you are using

```
response.sendRedirect("");
```

Your code should look like this

```
<%
if(traer.getFormapacretro().equals("RELACIONESLABORALES")&&tarea.getEstado()==4)
{
System.out.println("::::::::::::::::RELACIONES"+tarea.getEstado()+"LABORALES:::::::::::::::::::::");
response.sendRedirect("/html/controltareas/viewpacrl.jsp");
return;
}
else if(traer.getFormapacretro().equals("CAPACITACION")&&tarea.getEstado()==4)
{
System.out.println("::::::::::::::::CAPACITACION"+tarea.getEstado()+":::::::::::::::::::::");
response.sendRedirect("/html/controltareas/viewpaccapacita.jsp");
return;
}
%>
```